How to block a notification entirely?
I'm running a service extending NotificationListenerService:
class NotificationBlockerListenerService : NotificationListenerService() {
    override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
        cancelNotification(sbn.key)
    }
}

I does remove correctly the notification in the notification list (this list:)

But it doesn't block the notification bubble/snack from appearing (this one:)

Is it possible to block this bubble?

You could do anything if it was your push, show or not show to user as your wish.
However, as it said in comments below there is no option to intercept a push from other application.
Like, when push comes from FCM only Android and the application-receiver (whose push is that) can see it. You block it when it goes to Notifications, this part is made "inside the phone" by the application (or sometimes by Android) services. And it's too late, obviously, because it's already shown.
Theoretically you could try to subscribe to the same notification channel as those applications use. But first, you have to find the name of the channel from every other application. And second -- I'm just not sure it's applicable (it's just from the tip of my head).

NotificationBlockerListenerService is from my application, yes. I was to be able to block notifications from any app. In the screenshots, it is Instagram, but it can be anything like Facebook, WhastApp etc

Okay. In this case I can tell you one thing for sure -- you can't do what you want with this approach.
As you can see from the function name, it get's a notification been posted. So, at the moment you receive the notification it's already shown on user's screen.
Theoretically, if you want to hide notification fully, you have to intercept the Push itself (from FCM). But I'm afraid it's unreal even with Root permission.

Please add info like "tell more information" in the comments rather than the answer thread.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
